# working with sensible config data in blazor server - security vs. comfort

Tags: security, blazor, config

i have a blazor server-app which is running well. My app is doing some database operations, displays data from and saves data to the database.

Currently i have this db logindata direct inside my code to keep them not visible. But in case db-server or logindata changes it would require a complete recompile/upload of the app. So iam looking for a way to have the logindata outside the code for easy editing and still have them not visible to everybody in a protected way.

I could work with a json file and reduce filesecurity to be only readable by IUSR and Administrators, but iam unsure, it does not look really reliable.
Do you have a hint for me? How do you work with sensible data outside the code?

Thanks,
Hans

Comment: How often does your db login change? How do you plan on making changes to the config files when you db login changes?

Comment: Actually not very often. But beside of that it is a fundamental question how to work with private data in files and keep them confidential. A way could be to store data in an helper database and create a sql account for the lokal IUSR based on windows authentication.